# App runs fine the first time but crashes the second time

Tags: android, android-activity

My title is pretty self explanatory. Here's my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView browse;
    private TextView t;
    private String address="http://www.google.com";
    private int refresh, clearcache, time, refreshTime, cacheTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences gPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        address = gPrefs.getString("Address", "http://www.google.com");
        refresh = gPrefs.getInt("Refresh", 1);
        clearcache = gPrefs.getInt("ClearCache", 1);
        time = gPrefs.getInt("Time", 0);

        switch (time) {
        case 0:
            refreshTime = refresh * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            break;
        case 1:
            refreshTime = refresh * 60 * 1000;
            break;
        case 2:
            refreshTime = refresh * 1000;
            break;
        }

        switch (time) {
        case 0:
            cacheTime = clearcache * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            break;
        case 1:
            cacheTime = clearcache * 60 * 1000;
            break;
        case 2:
            cacheTime = clearcache * 1000;
            break;
        }

        browse = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

        browse.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browse.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        browse.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        browse.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browse.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browse.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        browse.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browse.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        browse.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browse.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        browse.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

        browse.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                t.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your stuff here
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                t.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
            }
        });

        try {
            browse.loadUrl(address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        refreshRRryan();
        cacheRRryan();
    }

    final Handler refreshhandler = new Handler();
    final Timer refreshtimer = new Timer();
    final Runnable refreshdoA = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            browse.reload();
        }
    };

    public void refreshRRryan() {
        TimerTask refreshtask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshhandler.post(refreshdoA);
            }
        };
        refreshtimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(refreshtask, refreshTime, refreshTime);
    }

    final Handler cachehandler = new Handler();
    final Timer cachetimer = new Timer();
    final Runnable cachedoA = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            browse.clearCache(true);
            getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webview.db");
            getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
        }
    };

    public void cacheRRryan() {
        TimerTask cachetask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cachehandler.post(cachedoA);
            }
        };
        cachetimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(cachetask, cacheTime, cacheTime);
    }

    @Override
    public File getCacheDir() {
        // NOTE: this method is used in Android 2.1

        return getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent("ABOUT");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.preferences:
            Intent p = new Intent("PREFS");
            startActivityForResult(p, 101);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And here's logcat:

```
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fit.world.browser/com.fit.world.browser.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2817)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.fit.world.browser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-17 11:08:05.997: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     ... 11 more
```

And I'm pretty sure my manifest is fine because the activity runs the first time.

Help me please.

Comment: which code is on 37 no line ?

Comment: Please show the code where you `put` and `commit` the `SharedPreference` edits.

Comment: I would put a `Log.d("debug",variable);` before the crash and see what it's printing out. The error is on line 37 of your main activity, which I'm guessing is `switch (time) {` so put a `Log.d("debug",time);` before the switch and see what it prints out whenever it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
refresh = gPrefs.getInt("Refresh", 1);
clearcache = gPrefs.getInt("ClearCache", 1);
time = gPrefs.getInt("Time", 0);
```

The first time the app run, it uses the default value you use (1,1,0) above.

But the second time, it certainly uses the data you've saved from a user input perhaps.

You must be saving it as a string and trying to retrieve it as an int...

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
You are trying to cast a String object to an Integer. That cannot be done. They are not of the same type.

The error tells you at what line of your file that happened, so you can correct it.
**MainActivity.java:37**